# MySQL 5.7.14 Community Server Installation stuck on macOS 10.12

Tags: mysql, macos, installation, freeze

While I was installing MySQL 5.7.14 Community Server edition on macOS 10.12 it got stuck at "Running Package Scripts...".

I tried quitting and restarting the installation procedure several times but the same thing happens every time. Please help me!

[image: Screenshot of the installation stuck point]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up deleting 5.7 and installing 5.6. Works great. I’m not sure if that is a solution for you, but it worked great for out needs.